# How to change order Listener in Azure Application gateway

Tags: azure, networking, azure-application-gateway, azure-waf

In Azure Application gateway, you can associate Listeners with the host name.
but, how to change the order of the listeners, since the choice is made in order.

Example:

```
Name:           port      host
listenet01       80       
listenet02       80       contoso.com
```

In this example, never is directed to listenet02.

How to change to:

```
Name:          port       host
listenet02      80        contoso.com
listenet01      80
```

Comment: No more, thank you for your information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it is not supported to reorder the listeners in the Application gateway, Microsoft is planning to add this feature.

See the uservoice here - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/33841291-reorder-the-listeners-on-the-application-gateway

Answer (score 0):

You can edit and save a listener and it will move it to the top of the list. As far as I know, this is the only way to change the order.